# How Can I load a Flashplayer in android?

Tags: javascript, android, iframe, flash

I have a video service in my country and I need to play a video of that in my application.

this is link of that video I need to play

the player is Flashplayer in the website

so how can I just load that flashplayer in my application ?

link iframe:

```
iframe src="http://www.aparat.com/video/video/embed/videohash/jMpRb/vt/frame" allowFullScreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" height="360" width="640" >
```

and Script Code :

```
div id="14481087503220637"> script type="text/JavaScript" src="http://www.aparat.com/embed/jMpRb?data[rnddiv]=14481087503220637&data[w]=640">
```

Comment: Adobe discontinued the Flash Player for Android years ago. Devices running Android 4.1+ will not have the Flash Player and cannot get it from the Play Store.

Comment: @CommonsWare so how can i use this service in my application , its like youtube

Comment: Ask the maintainers of the site what other streaming protocols that they support.

Comment: if you **must** install that bloated sack of malware - this may help - https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/installing-flash-player-android-devices.html